# Woocommerce: Managing software subscription API

Tags: wordpress, vb.net, plugins, woocommerce, subscriptions

I have an application **VB.NET Forms app** that I want to charge for the use, on a subscription basis.

How can I set this up with a wordpress site?

E.g. user registers on the site, purchases a subscription, then log in with the same details on the app which checks the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install [WooCommerce](https://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) free plugin and buy a subscription plugin for woocommerce:

- [Subscriptio - WooCommerce Subscriptions](http://codecanyon.net/item/subscriptio-woocommerce-subscriptions/8754068) *(the cheapest)*
- [WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) *(more expensive)*

Then you can bridge it through [WooCommerce API v3 VB.NET / C# library](http://www.softwarehorizont.com/2015/11/woocommerce-api-v3-vbnet-c-library.html). 
*(This part will be a little more difficult)*.

Answer (score 1):

make a licence.php on your wordpress based web site . That php script acts like a bridge between your application clients and your wordpress web site. If you could made an apllication needs charge for usage then you can use .net's webclient class so easily to get information from your wordpress database.